# Передать в контроллер значения двух переменных в качестве одного параметра

Tags: c#, mvc, razor

Есть два `@Html.DropDownListFor()`, один из которых предполагает выбор даты, а второй - времени события. Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли с помощью razor-а передать два значения в качестве одной строки в контроллер из представления? Т.е. получить в результате в контроллере одну переменную формата, например, "MM/dd/yyyy/HH/mm/ss", при том что из отдельных `DropDownListFor()` берутся дата: "MM/dd/yyyy" и время: "HH/mm/ss".

Возможно ли собрать эти строки вместе и передать в метод контроллера как одну строку?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам  нужна кастомная привязка модели. Механизм привязки модели в asp.net достаточно умён для простых и для большинства сложных моделей, но в подобных случаях он бессилен. Тут на помощь приходит возможность создания собственных привязчиков модели. Для этого вам потребуется создать класс, реализующий интерфейс `IModelBinder`. Проще это сделать, унаследовавшись от класса `DefaultModelBinder`.
Примерно так:

```
public class DateTimeModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var date = DateTime.Parse(request.Form.Get("date"));
        var time = TimeSpan.Parse(request.Form.Get("time"));
        date = DateTime.Today.Add(time);

        return date;
    }
}
```

а затем применить указать этот класс в качестве привязчика модели для вашего параметра. Вряд ли вы хотите делать приваязку модели таким образом везде в вашем проекте, поэтому стоит делать это с помощью атрибута для параметра вашего метода. Примерно так:

```
ActionResult MyAction([ModelBinder(typeof(DateTimeModelBinder))] DateTime arg)
```

Comment: DreamChild, спасибо за ответ. Похоже, это как раз то, что нужно. Единственное, если позволите, хотел уточнить, возможно ли использование такого метода для случая, когда в контроллер передается моделька и `DateTime arg` в данном случае просто одно из полей?

Comment: в этом случае вам надо добавить соответствующий атрибут для поля этого типа в самой модели. Либо, если есть необходимость, написать класс для привязки всей модели, включая и поле с датой

Comment: Все, кажется понял. Большое спасибо